# Django Url not leading to the proper template Beginner

Tags: python, django, url

I am a beginner trying to extend the Mozilla Django tutorial, and have run into a problem. I've looked here and on the official Django tutorial and can't find the answer. Basically, I have a list of authors and adjacent links to a delete form:

```
{% for author in author_list %}
<li>
<a href="{{ author.get_absolute_url}}">{{author.last_name }}<a>
<a href="% url 'author_delete' author.pk %">Delete</a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

This is the url pattern:

```
 urlpatterns+=[
   url(r'^author/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', views.AuthorDelete.as_view(), 
   name='author-delete'),
 ]
```

This is the views file:

```
class AuthorDelete(DeleteView):
  model = Author
  success_url = reverse_lazy('authors')
```

Somehow an identically structured titles page works without problem.

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem exactly? Are you running in any errors? What are you trying to do?

Comment: hover on the delete link in your browser and check where the link actually leads to, it seems to me that the urlpattern doesn't really capture the link.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your template. Change this line

```
<a href="% url 'author_delete' author.pk %">Delete</a>
```

To this

```
<a href="{% url 'author_delete' author.pk %"}>Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax errors. Notice the changes from the original:

```
{% for author in author_list %}
<li>
<a href="{{ author.get_absolute_url}}">{{author.last_name }}<a>
<a href="% url 'author_delete' author.pk %">Delete</a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

To this:

```
{% for author in author_list %}
<li>
<a href="{{ author.get_absolute_url }}">{{ author.last_name }}<a>
<a href="{% url 'author_delete' author.pk %}">Delete</a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Django's template syntax uses variables and tags. Variables accessed via `{{ some.variable }}` and tags being some sort of logical operation used via `{% for foo in bar %}...{% endfor %}` or `{% load static %}` for example.

Comment: If an answer is correct, please mark it as so. @purplebetter1